# How to add custom email headers in Google App Engine Mail API

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, gmail-api, email-headers

I need help on how to add several custom email headers when sending email using GAE's Mail API (Python) i.e. Message-id, person-id and etc.

But somehow, I don't see it in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.mail

I can receive emails and read custom email headers using the method below:
mail_message.original.**getitem**('mail_header')

But I don't know how to send an email with custom email headers.

Here is the code i use to send email:

```
mail.send_mail(sender=sender_address,
               to="handsome_me@yahoo.com",
               subject="gwapo",
               body="Hi")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you missed this line in the docs:

> PROPERTIES = set(['body', 'amp_html', 'sender', 'to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'attachments', 'headers', 'html', 'reply_to', 'subject'])

You can provide a `headers` parameter containing a list of custom headers.

Looking at the sources, the `headers` paramenter is subject to the following restrictions:

- must be a dict
- all values must be strings
- all keys must be ASCII
- key should be in the following white list: `Auto-Submitted`, `In-Reply-To`, `List-Id`, `List-Unsubscribe`, `On-Behalf-Of`, `References`, `Resent-Date`, `Resent-From`, `Resent-To`.

I'm afraid you won't be able to override `message-id` using AppEngine as it is not in the HEADERS_WHITELIST. I forgot how crippled AppEngine is, you may want to check [third-party email services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-messages). I've used mailgun and they allow arbitrary headers as long as they are prefixed by `X-` (just include a `h:X-My-Arbitrary-Header` in the payload). From the [AppEngine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/sending-messages):

> ## Sending Messages with Third-Party Services
>
> Python 2.7/3.7 |Java 8/11 |PHP 5/7 |Ruby |Go 1.9/1.11/1.12 |Node.js
>   Python 3.7 applications on App Engine can use third-party companies to send email, SMS messages, or make and receive phone calls. For example, you might send email to confirm business transactions, confirm the creation of user accounts, or send marketing communications.
>
> This page lists some examples of companies that provide communication services and client libraries for Python 3.7 applications on App Engine.
>
> Note: The services offered by these third-party companies are not covered by the App Engine Service Level Agreement.
>
> ### Mailgun
>
> Mailgun provides both RESTful APIs and client libraries for sending email. As a GCP project user, your first 30,000 messages are free every month. See the monthly pricing calculator on the sign up page for pricing on additional messages and volume discounts.
>
> Learn more about Mailgun:
>
> - [Mailgun developer documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/)
> - [Mailgun client libraries](https://documentation.mailgun.com/libraries.html#libraries)
>
> ...
>
> ### SendGrid
>
> You can use SendGrid to power your emails on App Engine. SendGrid can improve your deliverability and provide transparency into what actually happens to those emails your app sends. You can see statistics on opens, clicks, unsubscribes, spam reports and more with the SendGrid interface or its API.
>
> App Engine customers can send 12,000 emails every month for free by signing up for the SendGrid Email API plan through the Google Cloud Platform Console. Note that Google is compensated for customers who sign up for a paid account.
>
> Learn more about SendGrid:
>
> - [SendGrid developer documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/libraries.html)
> - [SendGrid client libraries](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/libraries.html)

I'm not affiliated with any of those and the original page mentions other services, I'm quoting mailgun because I've used it and know it works, and sendgrid because it is mentioned by OP.

Comment: ohhh thanks! I missed that! I will try it, but it is likely the answer. :)

Comment: Check my update, I'm not sure you will be able to override `message-id` as it is not in the white list.

Comment: Seems like it allows you to add headers, but not custom ones. It also takes in Dictionary objects. First error: "Invalid type for headers. Should be a dictionary."

When I used dictionary object I got the Second error: "Header "x-caller-number" is not allowed. "

hmm...

Comment: That is correct, I was using sendgrid and was able to add custom headers, but the client wanted some changes and I am exploring mail api again :/

It looks like Mail api won't let you add custom mail headers.

Comment: @JamesChing Yes, I think you will have to use a third-party service like sendgrid or mailgun. I've used only mailgun.

Comment: Right, as for header_whitelist, it is in the code:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/mail#EmailMessage


You can only add the following headers:

HEADER_WHITELIST = frozenset([
    'Auto-Submitted',
    'In-Reply-To',
    'List-Id',
    'List-Unsubscribe',
    'On-Behalf-Of',
    'References',
    'Resent-Date',
    'Resent-From',
    'Resent-To',
    ])

Answer (score 0):

Im working on devselz.com a service which allows unlimited emails to be sent / month. It uses a P2P with private servers, where on users can use their own servers (by installing a compatct SMTP provided by devselz.)

Here are the docs: https://devselz.com/support/